# VB.NET not able to read PLC registers, when connected to MySQL server installed on a 64 bit OS

Tags: mysql, vb.net, tcp, plc

This is the strangest problem i have ever faced. So here are the things i have:

1. VB application which reads a Fatek PLC through an Ethernet port, some SNMP traps, a SMS modem and listens on a port in order to receive some commands to execute.
2. MySQL server on 32 bit OS and MySQL server on 64 bit OS.

When the application is connected to a MySQL server which is on 32 bit OS there is no problem. It reads the PLC registers every 5 seconds with no problem.

But when the application is connected to a MySQL server, which is on a 64 bit OS, it's not able to read the PLC every 5 seconds, but gets to read it each minute.

I've tried every other possible combination and it only works when connected to MySQL server installed on a 32 bit OS and doesn't work when connected to MySQL server installed on 64 bit OS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How does the MySQL server factor into your application?  What role does it play (if any) in PC/PLC communications?  Are calls to the DB rolled into your PLC polling code? Threaded application?  Some code would help.

Comment: I write the values from the registers in MySQL and i don't know by any way how does it affect it.

Comment: So your HMI PC is reading directly from the PLC, then writing those values to a MySQL server on a different PC?  Which 32bit and 64bit OS is the MySQL server running on?  Windows?  Linux?  Something else?  Which version?  Which version of MySQL?  Can you show the code you use to read from the PLC and the code you use to write to the database?  Are they done in separate procedures?

Comment: Seems the problem is in the IPv6. I'll update when we've solved it. The MySQL server is running on Windows machines.